# Designing Simple Schema for Disaggregation of Demand Forecast

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, oracle11g

**Edit**: [*Details*] I am doing a simple database design task as a training exercise where I have to come up with a basic schema design for the following case:

I have a parent-child hierarchy of products (Raw Material > Work in Progress > End Product).

Orders are placed at each level.

Number of orders shall be viewable in weekly buckets for the next 6 months.

Demand forecast can be made for each product level.

Demand forecast is done for weekly buckets, for the next 6 months.

It's usually done at the higher level in hierarchy (Raw Material or Work in Progress)

It has to be disaggregated to a lower level (End Product)

There are 2 ways in which demand forecast can be disaggregated from a higher level to lower level:

1. User specifies percentage distribution for end product. Say, there's a forecast of 1000 for Work In Progress.. and user says I want 40% for End Product 1 and 60% for End Product 2 in bucket 10.. Then for 10th week (Sunday to Saturday) from now, forecast value for End Product 1 would be 400 and, for End Product 2 would be 600.
2. User says, just disaggregate according to orders placed against end products in Bucket 5, and orders in bucket 5 for End Product 1 and 2 are 200 and 800 respectively, then forecast value for EP1 would be ((200/1000) * 100)% and for EP2 would be ((800/1000) * 100)% of forecast for 'Work in Progress'.

Forecast shall be viewable in weekly buckets for the next 6 months and the ideal format should be:

`product name | bucket number | week start date | week end date | forecast value`

What would be the a basic ideal schema for such a requirement?

---

**Product_Hierarchy** table could look like this:

```
id  |   name                |   parent_id
__________________________________________
1   |   raw material        |   (null)
2   |   work in progress    |   1
3   |   end product 1       |   2
4   |   end product 2       |   2
```

---

Is this a good way to store orders?

**Orders**

```
id | prod_id | order_date | delivery_date | delivered_date
```

where,

`prod_id` is foreign key that references `id` of product_hierarchy table,

The orders for 26 weekly buckets can be selected as

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) TOTAL_ORDERS,
    WIDTH_BUCKET(
        delivery_date,
        SYSDATE,
        ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, 6), 
        TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') - TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, 6),'DD-MON-YYYY') ) / 7
    ) BUCKET_NO
FROM
    orders_table
WHERE
    delivery_date BETWEEN SYSDATE AND ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, 6);
```

But this will give weekly buckets starting from today irrespective of the day. I want them to be in Sunday to Saturday weeks.

Please help designing this database structure.

(Gonna be using Oracle 11g)

Comment: If forecast is a computed value, do **not** put a field for it. Using a virtual column where you calculate it on the fly, or a view if you prefer. This is the basic of relational database design, with normal forms, etc. Why not 3 tables with a field for the week, and another one for the order, just referencing the mother's one with a FK?

Comment: User can input forecast corresponding to a week bucket manually as well, which should be saved. Forecasted value will anyhow be saved for a higher level in hierarchy. The lower level might not have a value initially - but it might have after disaggregation. How should I approach this?

What do you suggest?

Comment: Well I don't know, I don't understand everything. :( Orders already exists in your table, they are a data, right? As entry data, you only have current-date, forecast. Do forecasts *have to be* split to the smaller level?

Comment: Yes, right, orders are data and there's a table for that. There's a table for product hierarchy which has data about products at various levels.

Forecasts have to be recorded at any level (user specified forecasts) .. and calculated forecasts = split from the higher level to the lower level.

Comment: I meant, can you have forecast raw_material=3, and all its son not precised?

Comment: Yes! I am thinking along this line right now.. One is to calculate forecast in a view, first, by summing up the orders at each level.. `prod_name | week_start_date | week_end_date | bucket_number | calculated_forecast`

then using this view's data to popular a forecast table .. all the above attributes and an additional column to store disaggregated forecast value, based on user input distribution..

Can you suggest a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Your last comment is exactly what I meant. Cool to see you got it!

Since I had started doing it, I finished an exemple code. The difference with what you were saying is separating what will change from what will not (`raw_material` VS `raw_material_hist`) using only date for the week, which *is monday*, and various check constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE raw_material 
  ( 
     material_id     NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
     material_blabla VARCHAR2(20) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE wip 
  ( 
     wip_id     NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
     parent_raw NUMBER REFERENCES raw_material(material_id), 
     wip_desc   VARCHAR2(20) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE end_product 
  ( 
     end_product_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
     parent_wip     NUMBER REFERENCES wip(wip_id), 
     description    VARCHAR2(20) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE rm_histo 
  ( 
     material_id NUMBER REFERENCES raw_material(material_id), 
     week_start  DATE CHECK (To_char(week_start, 'D')=1), 
     forecast    NUMBER(8) CHECK (forecast >0), 
     CONSTRAINT pk_rm_histo PRIMARY KEY (material_id, week_start) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE wip_histo 
  ( 
     wip_id            NUMBER REFERENCES wip(wip_id), 
     week_start        DATE CHECK(To_char(week_start, 'D')=1), 
     wip_user_forecast NUMBER(8) CHECK (wip_user_forecast>0), 
     CONSTRAINT pk_wip_histo PRIMARY KEY (wip_id, week_start) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE end_prod_histo 
  ( 
     end_product_id         NUMBER REFERENCES end_product(end_product_id), 
     week_start             DATE CHECK(To_char(week_start, 'D')=1), 
     end_prod_user_forecast NUMBER(8) CHECK (end_prod_user_forecast >0) 
  );
```

And at the end, indeed you use a view to see the forecasted things, or a materialized one if you have tons of data. By using a view, you do not duplicate the data, so it's safer and easier to change/update.

For your use cases 1 or 2, this does not deal with the database schema. At the end of the day it'll just be updating some value for the forecast, the logic of use cases 1 or 2 could go in a PL/SQL procedure or whatever you are using for the interface.

Edit: Also from your last comment you were mentionning having the forecasted manually set VS the computed one. So I added such a column, but credits go to you

Edit bis: As for the bucket number, just use a proper mask for the date, like `IW` or `WW`. These two changes which is the first week of the year.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Plouf .. but don't the `raw_material` , `wip` and `end_products` tables basically have the same structure. Take a look at the product_heirarchy table in my question..

    SELECT LEVEL,
  LPAD(' ', 2 * LEVEL - 1) || name AS product_level_name
 FROM product_hierarchy
 START WITH id = 1
 CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id;

Will help you visualize the parent-child relationship easily.

Comment: I thought your question was about alternative schemas. Because I know I'm not a huge fan of hierarchy inside a single table. Just do a few tries with the `connect by` and many lines... Whereas with several tables you can play around with indexes, optimizing the joins, partitioning...

Comment: The only concern is that if there are numerous product levels - things would soon go out of hand.

But, really, thanks a lot for your answers and comments - they gave me broader and clearer perspective. I have a solution in mind and I'll post a detailed answer very soon, upon validating my approach. Thanks @Plouf

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's the data model I came up with.

PRODUCT -- to store product information and maintain parent-child hierarchy

```
id  NUMBER  "Primary Key Not Null"                  
level_code  VARCHAR2    Not Null                    
name    VARCHAR2    Not Null                    
description VARCHAR2                        
parent_id   NUMBER  Foreign Key references PRODUCT(id)
```

ORDERS -- to store orders for products

```
id  NUMBER  "Primary Key Not Null"                  
prod_id     NUMBER  "Foreign Key references PRODUCT(id) Not Null"                   
order_type  VARCHAR2    "Not Null Default 'Default'"
order_qty   NUMBER  Not Null
order_date  NUMBER  Foreign Key references DATE_INFO(date_key)
delivery_date   NUMBER  "Foreign Key references DATE_INFO(date_key)
Check delivery_date >= order_date"
```

FORECAST -- to store forecast value for products (store value for higher levels, store value for lower levels after disaggregation from a parent)

```
id  NUMBER  "Primary Key Not Null"
product_id  NUMBER  "Foreign Key references PRODUCT(id) Not Null"
forecast_value  NUMBER  Not Null
week    NUMBER  "Foreign Key references DATE_INFO(date_key) Not Null"
```

DISAGGREGATION_RULES -- to store which method was used for disaggregating a value from a higher level to lower level and how much percentage got distributed to lower level

```
id  NUMBER  "Primary Key Not Null"
parent_product_id   NUMBER  "Foreign Key id references PRODUCT(id) Not Null"
child_product_id    NUMBER  "Foreign Key id references PRODUCT(id) Not Null"
method  VARCHAR2    Not Null                    
from_week   NUMBER  "Foreign Key references DATE_INFO(date_key) Not Null"
to_week NUMBER  "Foreign Key references DATE_INFO(date_key) Not Null Check end_week >= start_week"
percent_distribution    NUMBER  Not Null
```

DATE_INFO -- date dimension, has information about start date (has to be Saturday) and end date corresponding to the week in which a particular date falls

```
date_key    NUMBER  "Primary Key
Not Null"                   
full_date   DATE    Not Null                    
week_begin_date DATE    Not Null                    
week_end_date   DATE    Not Null
```

As for the bucket number / weeks thing.. I am calculating week start date (date on Saturday, in my case) with the following function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_week_start_date(v_bucket_num IN NUMBER)
  RETURN DATE
IS
  week_start_date DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT (TRUNC(SYSDATE+2, 'IW')-2) + ((v_bucket_num-1) * 7)
  INTO week_start_date FROM dual;
  RETURN week_start_date;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is SQL Server syntax, you can google for the equivalent oracle functions

```
DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, GETDATE(), 0), 0)
```

This will give you midnight (0:00:00) on the first day of the current week. What day this is depends on your system settings - you can use the Oracle eqivalent of DATEADD to mov it to the day you need.

I would rethink you schema, from your description it a heirachy is not the the concept that leaps to my mind - it sounds more like a sequence. I think you may be better off starting with your business objects and working back to the database rather than the other way around.

Comment: Can you explain more about your suggestion for schema? I am doing this task as a training exercise (details on what I need in question) - so I am open to rethinking my schema. I could use some guidance. Do you need any additional details?

Comment: OK, fundamentally computer programs are to solve real world problems. The basic premise of programming IMO is not to start with what the software can do but with how the problem is presently being solved and build a conceptual model of that. In general there will be things (objects in code) and processes (methods in code) that allow objects to be born, evolve and die. A database is only a way of storing the state of these. If you want to post a question with the specific details of your problem I will get more specific there.

Comment: I updated my question for more clarity. Please see if it helps in visualizing the case.