# Oracle PL SQL procedure to disaggregate value from parent to child

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor, dynamic-sql

I am working on a case where I have

1. Parent-Child hierarchy of products: [highest level] Raw Material *RM* > Work in Progress *WIP* > End Product *EP* [lowest level]
2. Orders for *End Products* for specific weeks
3. Forecast values for *Raw Material* or *Work in Progress* for specific weeks

My goal is to disaggregate forecast value for a specific RM or WIP for a particular week to some or all of child EPs of that RM or WIP for that particular week based on the number of orders for these children.

It simply means that if I have a RM, say RM1, which has 3 child EPs, say EP1, EP2 and EP3.. and I have a forecast value of 1000 for RM1 for week 2, then my goal is to split this forecast into 3 parts for the EPs based on calculated or specified percentage distribution for each EP.

User can choose which method to use for getting the percentage distribution:

1. ***Calculate*** : User says, disaggregate RM1 forecast value to EP1 and EP2 according to orders placed against them from 10th to 15th bucket (10th week from now's start date to 16th week from now's start date). So we calculate total orders for EP1 and EP2 from 10th to 15th weekly bucket individually and calculate percentage distribution as follows: EP1 orders / (EP1 + EP2 orders) * 100 % and (EP2 orders) / (EP1 + EP2 orders) * 100 %, respectively.
2. ***Specify*** : User says, 20% to EP1, 50% to EP2 and 10% to EP3

Then we simply divide the RM1 forecast value 1000 for week 2 for each EP according to the percentage we calculated or got above and store it as the forecast value for EP for week 2 in the same table.

The method chosen for disaggregation is stored in another table along with parent_id, child_id, percentage for child, start bucket's start date, (end bucket+1)'s start date

I have the following tables:

1. **Products**, for storing product information and maintains a parent-child hierarchy (Raw Material > Work in Progress > End Product)
2. **Orders**, for storing orders for lowest level of hierarchy (End Product).
3. **Forecast Value**, for storing forecast value (a number) for a product for a specific week
4. **Method Of Disaggregation**, forecast table stores forecast value for a product for a specific week at higher level (Raw Material) of hierarchy initially. That value is disaggregated for its child levels (some End Products) and stored in forecast table itself. 
   Method of Disaggregation stores which *method* was used to
   disaggregate forecast value from which *parent* to which *child* and
   how much was the *percentage distribution* for this child.
5. **Date Info** date dimension, has information about start date (has to be Saturday) and end date corresponding to the week in which a particular date falls

I posted my data model here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14881277/891424 and here's a function and a couple of procedures that I have written so far:

*Function to find out week start date corresponding to a given bucket*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_week_start_date(v_bucket_num IN NUMBER)
  RETURN DATE
IS
  week_start_date DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT (TRUNC(SYSDATE+2, 'IW')-2) + ((v_bucket_num-1) * 7)
  INTO week_start_date FROM dual;
  RETURN week_start_date;
END;
```

*Procedure to return all child EPs of the given parent*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_eps(
  v_parent IN NUMBER,
  v_children_of_parent OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
  v_children SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_children_of_parent FOR
  SELECT id, name FROM (
    SELECT
      CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF isleaf, p.id, p.name
    FROM
      inf_product p
    WHERE p.level_code = 'EP'
      START WITH id = 1
      CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
    )
  WHERE isleaf = 1;
END;
```

*Procedure that does the disaggregation of forecast values (incomplete)*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE inf_disaggregate(v_parent_id IN NUMBER, v_bucket_start IN NUMBER, v_bucket_end IN NUMBER)
IS
  /* Parent Product ID from input */
  v_parent_prod_id NUMBER;

  /* All the children of parent specified in the input */
  child_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    child_id    NUMBER;
    child_name  VARCHAR2(40);

  /* Forecast Bucket Info */
  vbucket_start NUMBER;
  vbucket_end NUMBER;
  vbucket_diff NUMBER;    -- loop over vbucket_diff + 1

  /* Date corresponding to input buckets */
  vbucket_start_date DATE;
  vbucket_end_date DATE;

  /* Exceptions */
  invalid_bucket EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( invalid_bucket, -20001 );
BEGIN
  v_parent_prod_id := v_parent_id;

  vbucket_start := v_bucket_start;
  vbucket_end := v_bucket_end;
  vbucket_diff := vbucket_end - vbucket_start;

  IF vbucket_diff < 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Bucket numbers not in the correct order' );
  END IF;

  IF vbucket_start < 1 OR vbucket_start > 26 OR vbucket_end < 1 OR vbucket_end > 26 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Bucket value must be within 1 to 26' );
  END IF;

  /* Get first day of the week corresponding to the buckets */
  vbucket_start_date := get_week_start_date(vbucket_start);
  vbucket_end_date   := get_week_start_date(vbucket_end);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vbucket_start);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vbucket_end);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vbucket_diff);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vbucket_start_date);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vbucket_end_date);

  /* Get all child EPs for the specified parent */
  get_eps(v_parent => v_parent_prod_id, v_children_of_parent => child_cursor);

  LOOP 
    FETCH child_cursor
    INTO  child_id, child_name;
    EXIT WHEN child_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(child_id || ' | ' || child_name);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE child_cursor;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN invalid_bucket
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1 , 80));
END;
/
```

*Running the procedure*

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CALL inf_disaggregate(5, 10, 12);
```

**QUESTION 1:** How do I create a package or procedure to accomplish this task?

**QUESTION 2:** How do I get rid of the SYS_REFCURSOR and use dynamic sql instead? (I should probably get rid of child_name as well, since IDs alone would serve me well for all purposes)

**QUESTION 3**: How to get method of disaggregation and in case of ***specify***, percentage as user input?

Comment: The answer is no answer. Don't use a package to accomplish this task. In general, you will want to get away from a procedural means to disaggregate. What you want is a good model (3NF or better) of your data that captures your data completely disaggregated and then employ declarative SQL to get at it in whatever aggregates you desire. Once you start seeing dependencies on DUAL in your procedures, run away from that approach as fast as you can.